# ReactiveLIst ItemsAdded

Tags: c#, reactiveui

Regarding ReactiveList, and the ItemsAdded property. I had a list of Journal items stored in a ReactiveList:

```
public ReactiveList<account.JournalViewModel> JournalEntries { get; private set; }
```

And I have a Readonly property to display the Balance of all the Journal Items:

```
readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<decimal> _balance;
public decimal Balance { get { return _balance.Value; } }
```

In the Constructor of the ViewModel, I instantiate the ReactiveList, and set the ObservableAsPropertyHelper:

```
this.JournalEntries = new ReactiveList<account.JournalViewModel>();
this.JournalEntries.ChangeTrackingEnabled = true;
this.WhenAnyObservable(vm => vm.JournalEntries.ItemsAdded)
    .Select(_ => this.JournalEntries.Sum(j => j.CreditAmount) - this.JournalEntries.Sum(j => j.DebitAmount))
    .ToProperty(this, vm => vm.Balance, out _balance);
```

Then, still in the constructor but further down, I add items to the ReactiveList:

```
foreach (var j in journalEntries)
     this.JournalEntries.Add(new account.JournalViewModel(j, this));
```

However this does not set the Balance property, and I don't know why. However if I change the property to a regular ol' Observable:

```
decimal _balance;
public decimal Balance { get { return _balance; } set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _balance, value); } }
```

And, in the constructor, Subscribe to the ItemsAdded Observable:

```
this.WhenAnyObservable(vm => vm.JournalEntries.ItemsAdded)
    .Subscribe(_ => this.Balance = this.JournalEntries.Sum(j => j.CreditAmount) - this.JournalEntries.Sum(j => j.DebitAmount));
```

When I add the Journal items, the desired result is achieved. I was hoping someone better skilled than I am could answer why the first method won't work. Is there a way to make it work that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 2):

What you've likely discovered is lazy subscription.  `ObservableAsPropertyHelper` doesn't subscribe to the source observable until `Value` is accessed for the first time - this is a performance / memory optimisation.

As you probably don't access this during construction, the addition of items will have been missed by the time the property subscribes. If you access your `Balance` property between declaring it and adding an item, the property should be set.

Generally the approach for this is to ensure the observable will produce an initial value on subscription, for example:

```
JournalEntries.ItemsAdded.Select(_ => Unit.Default)
     .StartWith(Unit.Default)
     .Select(_ => JournalEntries.Sum(x => x.CreditAmount - x.DebitAmount))
     .ToProperty(this, x => x.Balance, out _balance);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Charles, and you were exactly right, it was the Lazy Subscription causing the issue. I tried your method, but it still didn't load the variable, but when I made a call to the property 'Balance' after the ToProperty call, but before loading all the Journal Items, it did performed as expected. Can you think of a way to avoid having to make the Property call? Really just curious at this point. Seems kind of like a hack to have to call the Property for no reason other than to get it to start listening.

Comment: I tried my method in a very basic app, then added some items, then checked `Balance` and the total was correct.  Are you sure you included the `StartWith`?